# Count numbers between parenthesis in string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have string that looks like this

```
"(1 4 3 2 12 7 10 5)(9 11)(4 3 2 3 2 1)"
```

Is there a way that I can count the amount of numbers between two brackets and get a list like

```
[8,2,6]
```

where 8 = length of the first bracket counting the amount of numbers?

Comment: Have you heard of [Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)?

Comment: I have not. Is there a module for it?

Comment: Yes [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module!

Comment: ans = [len(i.split(" ")) for i in '(1 4 3 2 12 7 10 5)(9 11)(4 3 2 3 2 1)'.split(')(')]

Comment: best thing is to use regex as suggested by @bro-grammer

Comment: seems dumb to encode data this way...why do you have string like this in first place and do you have control over this?

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way using a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to obtain a list of strings with the digits between parenthesis and a list comprehension to count the numbers within them:

```
s = '(1 4 3 2 12 7 10 5)(9 11)(4 3 2 3 2 1)'
import re
l = re.findall(r'\(((?:\d+\s*)+)\)', s)
# ['1 4 3 2 12 7 10 5', '9 11', '4 3 2 3 2 1']
[len(i.split()) for i in l]
# [8, 2, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a naive solution

```
def getlist(input_string):
    output = []
    count = 0
    for i in range(1, len(input_string)-1):
        char = input_string[i]
        if char == "(" :
            output.append(count)
            count = 0
        if char.isdigit() and not input_string[i+1].isdigit():
            count += 1
    output.append(count)
    return output
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split for every occurrence of open and closed parentheses ie ')(' then split for each space

```
def get_lengths(s):
    list1=s.split(")(")
    return [len(x.split()) for x in list1]

s=input()
print(get_lengths(s))
```